# comment django errno 22

Tags: python, django, errno

Hi i try add comment to my django blog procject and i get OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "C:\Users\marci\PycharmProjects\08.04\blog\templates\"

so my urls

```
  path('<int:a_id>/addcomment', views.addcomment, name='addcomment'),
```

views.py

```
def addcomment(request, a_id):
article = get_object_or_404(Articles,id=a_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.article = article
        comment.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/article/%s' % a_id)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
    template = 'addcomment.html'
    context = {'form': form}

return render_to_response(request,template,context)
```

addcomment.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block article %}

<form action="/article/{{ article.id }}/addcomment/" method="post" class="form-horizontal well">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" name="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

thx

Comment: Have you added `article` to your context somewhere?

Comment: no i dont  i followed the instruction of this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fatQJKeGWP8&t=712s                
         how it should be ??

Comment: well in the code you've shown you have not passed `article` to the template and your url patterns in the template do not match those in `urls.py` so try fixing both these first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `render` instead of `render_to_response`. You should also include `article` in the template context if you use it. Deindent the `template` and `contect` lines, so that the view works for invalid post requests.

```
def addcomment(request, a_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Articles,id=a_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template = 'addcomment.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'article': article}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: thx but do u know why  return HttpResponseRedirect('/article/%s' % a_id) didnot returned me to a page i was before /article/1 but  it go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/article//addcomment/ ?

Comment: That redirect line would not take you there. You would get that URL from the link `/article/{{ article.id }}/addcomment/` if `article` was not sent. You can add some `print("...")` or logging to follow where your code is going.